# exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException root cause java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

Everytime I run this jsp I get the following error exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is my code:

```
<%@page import="Business.Account"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Account Summary Page CHATTA</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
         body {background-color: powderblue;}
         h1   {color: blue;}
         p    {color: red;}
         div {text-align-center;}
      </style>
   </head>

       <% 
           Account a1 = (Account)session.getAttribute("a1");
           %>
      <h1 align="center"> CHATTABANK SUMMARY</h1>
      <br>
      </br>
      <form>
         <div>
            <label for="AcctNo">Accnt ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name ="AccntNo" value="<%=a1.getAcctNo()%>"/></br>
            <label for="CustID">Cust ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CUSTID" value="<%=a1.getCid()%>"/></br>
            <label for="Type">Type: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Type" value="<%=a1.getType()%>"/></br>
            <label for="Balance">Balance:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Balance" value="<%=a1.getBalance()%>"/></br>
         </div>
         <div>
         <input type="submit" name="subBtn" value="lookup"/>

         <input type="reset" name="rstBtn" value="clear"/>
      </form>

</html>
```

Let me know, if any more code is required.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the case where the session does not contain the attribute "a1" to avoid potential NullPointerExceptions calling methods on a null Account reference.  After you retrieve the "a1" attribute, you should also check that the object is actually a Business.Account object to prevent class cast related exceptions.

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: If the session does not contain an attribute "a1" then when you call session.getAttribute("a1") it will return null.  Calling <null>.getAcctNo() (or any other method on null) will give you a NullPointerException.

Comment: it should be in the session cuz on my servlet its             HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("AcctNo", AcctNo);
            System.out.println("Acct in session");

Comment: Your JSP code above says session.getAttribute("a1"), but your servlet code says session.setAttribute("AcctNo", AcctNo).  Unless you have session.setAttribute("a1", ...) somewhere in your servlet you won't find it in your JSP.

Comment: i edited it and it still gives the same error            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("a1", a1);
            System.out.println("Acct in session");

Comment: Have a look here https://gist.github.com/usirin/8561182 for an example of printing out everything that is in the session from a JSP page for debugging